# EventKit saveEvent is not working in iOS 7

Tags: events, ios7, calendar

I have added following code in my application.It is working fine if [comps setYear:1] but if i change year value to 2 or greater than 2 code does not show me any error but also not adding any event in calender. This happens in iOS 7 only. But if I run the same code on iOS 6 , its working correctly & event gets added in calender successfully. Is there any restriction in iOS 7 for adding future events ?

```
-(void)addEvent{
    EKEventStore *es = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    BOOL needsToRequestAccessToEventStore = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined);

    if (needsToRequestAccessToEventStore) {
        [es requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (granted) {
                [self setEventForStore:es];
            } else {

            }
        }];
    } else {
        BOOL granted = (authorizationStatus == EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized);
        if (granted) {
            [self setEventForStore:es];


        } else {

        }
    }
}

-(void)setEventForStore:(EKEventStore*)store{
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Event 4";

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    // comps.day =3650;
    comps.day=5;
    comps.hour=1;
    comps.year=2;
    NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    event.startDate = sevenDays;

    NSDate *sevenDays1 = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];;
    // duration = 1 h
    event.endDate = sevenDays1;

    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever dealing with dates through components, please set them in the following fashion:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[comps setDay:05];
[comps setMonth:01];
[comps setYear:2014]; //instead of adding a single digit number like so: 2

//followed by your code...
NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
//...
```

**UPDATE 1**

You mentioned that your event is not being saved in the calendar when you slightly adjust the integer values in your NSDate's components. One quick way to see whats happening is by NSLogging your date. See what the ouput is before you try to add it to your calendar.

```
//Right after this below line
NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

//Add the code here so we can see what `sevenDays` prints out.
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sevenDays];
NSLog(@"Seven Days date = %@", strDate);
```

Comment: but my code is working fine if i set year=1 then what is issue with year=2?I tried with your code but still not showing any event in calender.

Comment: if i use [comps setDay:05];[comps setMonth:01];[comps setYear:2014]; then console output is Seven Days date = 19-02-4028

Comment: @Nitin Ok understood. It adds to the current date. so now the question is why there is an error when you write 2 in the year component. Maybe it crashes because in 2 years time the earth will explode, thats why the date does not show up in the calendar? :P

Comment: @Nitin What is printed out when you write your own numbers as written in your original post? You could be looking at the wrong date and time? :)

Comment: no error & crash for year=2,but my code is not adding any event which has year=>2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45172/discussion-between-pavan-and-nitin)